# Retorno de Stored Procedure em PHP com PDO

Tags: php, pdo, stored-procedures

Tenho uma Stored Procedure no MS SQL Server com a seguinte especificação:

`PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetKey] (@TABLE varchar(30), @KEY INT OUTPUT )`

Não consigo pegar o valor de @KEY. Já tentei várias dicas aqui e em outros sites e não funciona.
No ADODB funcionava assim

```
$Result = $Conn->execute("declare @RETVAL integer EXEC dbo.GetKey 'Empresa', @RETVAL output SELECT @RETVAL");
$Empresa=$Result->fields[0];
```

No MS SQL Management Studio também funciona.

A última tentativa que fiz foi:

```
$out = 0;
$Result = $ConnLocal->prepare("DECLARE @RETVAL INT; EXECUTE dbo.GetKey 'Empresa', @RETVAL OUTPUT; SELECT @RETVAL"); 
$Result->execute();
$Row = $Result->fetch();
$out = $Row[0];

var_dump($out);
```

E dá o erro "The active result for the query contains no fields.".

Comment: precisa usar o `bindParam` para poder definir que o parâmetro é de output, senão não vai retonar o valor

Comment: Mesmo com o bindParam continua voltando vazio.